# File uploading in codeigniter with adding link to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to upload a file in a certain file if a file is chosen from the input file tag

```
<input name="file1" type="file" id="addimage1">
```

I want to know how to deal it in models. I want to send the link of the image to the database.

When I was not using code-igniter I was doing this:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file1']['name']) ) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"],'assets/results/'.$myid.'/'. $_FILES["file1"]["name"]);
    $link1='assets/results/'.$myid .'/' . $_FILES["file1"]["name"];      
}
```

How can I do this in Code-igniter.

Comment: read documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user guide states:

```
//after uploading config
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfileinputname'))
                {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                        //here add to db
                        $this->file_model->add_link_to_db($data['filename']);

                        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
                }
}
```

And inside your model:

```
public function add_link_to_db($filename) {
    return $last_id = $this->db->insert('mytable', ['name'=>$filename]);
}
```